# Making WebRequest with OAuth 2.0 in C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make a simple call to a authorization Server with OAuth 2.0.

And I am very new to OAuth 2.0.

How do I make a call to the Authorization Server to get back my access token to send in the request header of request (if I am wording that correctly).

Below is what I have, Thanks in advance to any help.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Uri);
request.Method = "POST";

var uri = new Uri(Uri);               

string postData = output;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

IAuthorizationState authorization = null;

AuthorizationServerDescription serviceDecription = new AuthorizationServerDescription
{
    AuthorizationEndpoint = uri,                    
};

WebServerClient client = new WebServerClient(serviceDecription, Key, Secret);

client.AuthorizeRequest(request, authorization);                

using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    if (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What AS? how do users authenticate?

Typically, OAuth2 flows require user interaction with a browser (like described in [this doc](https://docs.auth0.com/protocols#1)). It'd be great if you could add more context to what you are trying to do.

There are plenty of frameworks that you could use to avoid having to deal with lower level details of OAuth.